# Is it now a good time to buy rotating Magic Cards?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

There are many cards from the RTR block and M14 that I want just for my collection and not for play (maybe just some casual play), for example, I would like to buy a Domri Rade and a Kalonian Hydra. Right now the prices for these and many other cards are reasonable but I am not in a hurry to buy NOW since I only want the cards for my collection.

In my case, when is the best moment to buy the cards? I have read some people saying that NOW is the best moment, but in other places I also have read that maybe it would be wise to wait until the release or pre release week for Khans, while others suggest to wait until December.

Based on your experience, what do you recommend?

Thank you.

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of [What, generally, happens to card prices when a new set is released?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/15528/what-generally-happens-to-card-prices-when-a-new-set-is-released) Also, the answers are likely to be purely speculative.

Comment: Well, the question being pointed as possible duplicate is more about when to buy cards after a new set is released, my question is more about when to buy cards when a set is about to rotate or leave a particular format (Standard in this case).

Comment: They should both be closed as pure speculation anyway. I stated this on the older question, nobody listened, and the answer ended up saying exactly what I said. It's all just speculation.

Comment: @Rainbolt, speculation (in the sense of "supposition" which you contest both questions to be) is different from the investment practice called speculation which both questions touch upon.

Comment: He is asking what we would do based on our experience, the question itself asks for opinions/speculations.

Comment: It seems clear they're not duplicates; the older one is asking about buying cards from a new set with the intention of using them while they're in standard, and this one is about buying cards as they're rotating out.

Comment: As for whether this is purely opinion, well, there is certainly real evidence to base an answer on, especially if the OP is willing to simply ask "what has generally happened in the past?" - a *lot* of sets have rotated out of standard, and presumably some people have a pretty good idea how the prices varied over time at that point. (Rainbolt's comment on spocot's answer fairly clearly demonstrates this is possible.)

Comment: While this isn't a rules question, I'm surprised at the assumption that answers will need to be primarily opinion based. A good answer should be possible, should include some/lots of data, and, I think, be fairly easy to evaluate objectively.

Answer (score 6):

This answer is based on the very weak assumption that history will repeat itself.

When this answer was written, cards rotated once per year. [Wizards of the Coast is moving to two rotations per year](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/mm/metamorphosis). This will drastically change the pattern described below.

---

Innistrad was the first set of a block that rotated in **October 2013**. The rares and mythics that are not seeing play in Modern or Legacy from that set trended towards an all time low around **December 2013** before finally beginning to rise due to being out of print.

*If* Return to Ravnica follows the same pattern, the rares and mythics from the set that are not seeing play in Modern or Legacy will trend towards an all time low around **December 2014** before finally beginning to rise due to being out of print.

I used the price history line charts on [TCGPlayer.com](http://www.tcgplayer.com/) as a reference. I used my own experience to determine what cards see play in Modern and Legacy.

Comment: You don't really have to leave this as an assumption. If you looked at similar data for some previous rotations and older sets, you could figure out how reliable this conclusion is. If the pattern is pretty consistent, it's pretty likely to keep repeating (modulo things shifting around with the new rotation schedule), and if it varies a ton, then you can just conclude it's a bit unpredictable.

Comment: I simply didn't realize that the data wasn't available. You don't have to convince me that it's hard to tell how accurate this is from one data point. Also, perhaps it's fair to say that even if the exact time is variable, you'd at least expect the broad pattern to hold: the price fell *after* it rotated out, but didn't stay down forever.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I would wait a little bit. As soon as Khans of Tarkir hits shelves, the demand for cards from RTR block will drop as it will no longer be legal in standard, so I would buy RTR cards like a week after the Khans release to wait for the prices to drop/become stable. You can most likely safely buy M14 as a lot of it has been reprinted, and it is close to rotation as well. It's prices appear to have stabilized and won't change much in the future.

Comment: 2014 is still legal in standard.